# Gradle 7.1.1 Could not find jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin

Tags: maven, gradle

I was using gradle 5.x until now and am trying to upgrade to 7.1.1. With this, I am running into this error -

```
> Could not find jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.36.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jp/classmethod/aws/gradle-aws-plugin/0.36/gradle-aws-plugin-0.36.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/jp/classmethod/aws/gradle-aws-plugin/0.36/gradle-aws-plugin-0.36.pom
     Required by:
         project : > jp.classmethod.aws:jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.plugin:0.36
         project : > jp.classmethod.aws.s3:jp.classmethod.aws.s3.gradle.plugin:0.36
```

In my build.gradle -

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    //id 'maven' //this does not work with 7.1.1 either
    id 'jp.classmethod.aws' version '0.36'
    id 'jp.classmethod.aws.s3' version '0.36'
}
```

From the error, it is looking for the pom in -

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jp/classmethod/aws/gradle-aws-plugin/0.36/gradle-aws-plugin-0.36.pom
```

when actually, it is present in -

```
https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/jp/classmethod/aws/jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.plugin/0.36/jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.plugin-0.36.pom
```

I tried specifying the repository this way -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        //jcenter() //gradle 7.1.1 does not like this
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/jp/classmethod/aws/jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.plugin/0.36/" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/jp/classmethod/aws/s3/jp.classmethod.aws.s3.gradle.plugin/0.36/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.org.scoverage:gradle-scoverage:4.0.1"
        classpath "jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.36"
        classpath "jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.36"
    }
}

apply plugin: "jp.classmethod.aws"
apply plugin: "jp.classmethod.aws.s3"
```

in which case it gives me this -

```
> Could not find jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.36.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jp/classmethod/aws/gradle-aws-plugin/0.36/gradle-aws-plugin-0.36.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/jp/classmethod/aws/gradle-aws-plugin/0.36/gradle-aws-plugin-0.36.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/jp/classmethod/aws/jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.plugin/0.36/jp/classmethod/aws/gradle-aws-plugin/0.36/gradle-aws-plugin-0.36.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/jp/classmethod/aws/s3/jp.classmethod.aws.s3.gradle.plugin/0.36/jp/classmethod/aws/gradle-aws-plugin/0.36/gradle-aws-plugin-0.36.pom
```

Any clues how to fix this?
Thanks!!